Error After Deploying Next Project: Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information)
Error after deploying Next project:

Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information). Digest: 3526612386

I have successfully build and deployed, My Next 14 application and it began to see this error page, when I try to navigate to another route, but the authentication is okey
check the project here : applink
check the code from here: gitcode
I have tried to fix by redeploying several times But it doesnt fixed, And checked ENVs also, But all of these are worthless, IDK what is the issue on this.

Your question should contain the details to solve the issue. Please don't ask people to go to 3rd party sites which probably will even change after you fix the issue, making the question then obsolete / wrong.
